# Git push from windows pc to aws ec2 machine fails

Tags: ubuntu, git, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I've followed the steps in this tutorial:
http://cuppster.com/2011/05/12/diy-node-js-server-on-amazon-ec2

but when I came to the step "push our local code changes to the remote repository" I got an error.

I'm running a Windows 7 pc and using putty to access my AWS EC2 instance. My Git client is msysgit.

When I try to push to ec2 I get the following error:

> Pushing to
>   ssh://ubuntu@ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/home/ubuntu/repository
>   Permission denied (publickey). fatal: The remote end hung up
>   unexpectedly

I've tried using the almighty Google machine but I can't seem to type in the correct search terms to get an answer that works.

Any pointers that can make the push possible would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You need to copy your public SSH key to the server. Done by using `pscp.exe` and the command (in command prompt):

```
"c:\Program Files\Putty\pscp.exe" id_rsa.pub ubuntu@ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Where

- first part is the path to `pscp.exe`
- 2nd part is my public part of my SSH key and
- 3rd part is `username@remote_computer:path_on_remote_computer`

`pscp.exe` can be found at the [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) download page.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for the answer, just adding my 2 cents,

we need to add the current aws key to login using pscp

```
"c:\Program Files\Putty\pscp.exe" id_rsa.pub -i "current_aws_key" ubuntu@ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

Also we need to use the new key the next time we need to putty into the linux.